# How to do WaitAll with Akka.Net?

Tags: akka.net

I have a hierarchy of actors in Akka.Net and am wondering whether I've chosen the right way to do something, or if there are better/simpler ways to achieve what I want.

My specific example is that I'm constructing a **User** actor in response to a user logging into the system, and when constructing this actor there are two pieces of data I need in order to complete the construction of the actor.

If this were regular .NET code I might have something like the following...

```
public Task<User> LoadUserAsync (string username)
{
  IProfileService profileService = ...;
  IMessageService messageService = ...;

  var loadProfileTask = profileService.GetUserProfileAsync(username);
  var loadMessagesTask = messageService.GetMessagesAsync(username);

  Task.WaitAll(loadProfileTask, loadMessagesTask);

  // Now construct the user from the result of both tasks
  var user = new User
  {
    Profile = loadProfileTask.Result,
    Messages = loadMessagesTask.Result
  }

  return Task.FromResult(user);
}
```

Here I use WaitAll to wait for the subordinate tasks to complete, and let them run concurrently.

My question is - if I wanted to do the same in Akka.Net, would the following be the most regular way to do this? Pictorially I've created the following...

[image: Actor Hierarchy]

When I create my User actor, I then construct a (temporary) User Loader Actor, whose job it is to get the full user details by calling to the Profile actor and the Messages actor. The leaf actors that get the data are as follows...

```
public class UserProfileLoader : ReceiveActor
{
    public UserProfileLoader()
    {
        Receive<LoadUserRequest>(msg =>
        {
            // Load the user profile from somewhere
            var profile = new UserProfile();

            // And respond to the Sender
            Sender.Tell(profile);
            Self.Tell(PoisonPill.Instance);
        });
    }
}

public class UserMessagesLoader : ReceiveActor
{
    public UserMessagesLoader()
    {
        Receive<LoadUserRequest>(msg =>
        {
            // Load the messages from somewhere
            var messages = new List<Message>();

            // And respond to the Sender
            Sender.Tell(messages);
            Self.Tell(PoisonPill.Instance);
        });
    }
}
```

It doesn't really matter where they get the data from for this discussion, but both simply respond to a request by returning some data.

Then I have the actor that coordinates the two data gathering actors...

```
public class UserLoaderActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public UserLoaderActor()
    {
        Receive<LoadUserRequest>(msg => LoadProfileAndMessages(msg));
        Receive<UserProfile>(msg =>
        {
            _profile = msg;
            FinishIfPossible();
        });

        Receive<List<Message>>(msg =>
        {
            _messages = msg;
            FinishIfPossible();
        });
    }

    private void LoadProfileAndMessages(LoadUserRequest msg)
    {
        _originalSender = Sender;
        Context.ActorOf<UserProfileLoader>().Tell(msg);
        Context.ActorOf<UserMessagesLoader>().Tell(msg);
    }

    private void FinishIfPossible()
    {
        if ((null != _messages) && (null != _profile))
        {
            _originalSender.Tell(new LoadUserResponse(_profile, _messages));
            Self.Tell(PoisonPill.Instance);
        }
    }

    private IActorRef _originalSender;
    private UserProfile _profile;
    private List<Message> _messages;
}
```

This just creates the two subordinate actors, sends them a message to get cracking, and then waits for both to respond before sending back all the data that's been gathered to the original requestor.

So, does this seem like a reasonable way to coordinate two disparate responses, in order to combine them? Is there an easier way to do this than craft it up myself?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: I don't know if you need separate actor as a fasade for receiving only 2 replies. Couldn't `User` actor send those two requests directly?

Comment: I could indeed get the user actor to do all of this work, but as the User actor will most likely have even more stuff to do, I've chosen to split out the responsibility here to a Loader. Regardless of the distribution of work though, does the above make sense and/or is there a better/less code/more standard way to do this?

Comment: Are there anything very specific going on in the profile and message actors or are they only fetching data from a DB?
if so, I would probably just wrap that up in some async method that does a `WhenAll` on both subtasks and then return that task so the caller can `PipeTo(Self)` when done.. I know we preach "push dangerous work to children" but one need to consider if you really benefit from that or if it just result in code bloat..

Answer (score 2):

Thanks folks, so I've now simplified the actor significantly into the following, based on both Roger and Jeff's suggestions...

```
public class TaskBasedUserLoader : ReceiveActor
{
    public TaskBasedUserLoader()
    {
        Receive<LoadUserRequest>(msg => LoadProfileAndMessages(msg));
    }

    private void LoadProfileAndMessages(LoadUserRequest msg)
    {
        var originalSender = Sender;
        var loadPreferences = this.LoadProfile(msg.UserId);
        var loadMessages = this.LoadMessages(msg.UserId);

        Task.WhenAll(loadPreferences, loadMessages)
            .ContinueWith(t => new UserLoadedResponse(loadPreferences.Result, loadMessages.Result), 
                TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent & TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
            .PipeTo(originalSender);
    }

    private Task<UserProfile> LoadProfile(string userId)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new UserProfile { UserId = userId });
    }

    private Task<List<Message>> LoadMessages(string userId)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new List<Message>());
    }
}
```

The LoadProfile and LoadMessages methods will ultimately call a repository to get the data, but for now I have a succinct way to do what I wanted.

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. Watch out for AttachedToParent, the "parent" here is not Task.WhenAll, it's the current task that is calling LoadProfileAndMessages (in this case there are none). And you use & instead of | to combine flags, so you end up with zero.

Comment: By the way, my use of TaskContinuationOptions was copied from the Petabridge article on using PipeTo here - https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-async-actors-using-pipeto/. So I guess that needs to be updated too as there's two instances of this same issue there too.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO that's a valid process, as you fork action and then join it.

BTW you could use `this.Self.GracefulStop(new TimeSpan(1));` instead of sending poison pill.

Comment: Thanks - I'd not looked at the ways of stopping an Actor, having read this - http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/stopping-actors I have changed the code to Context.Stop(Self).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of Ask, WhenAll and PipeTo:

```
var task1 = actor1.Ask<Result1>(request1);
var task2 = actor2.Ask<Result2>(request2);

Task.WhenAll(task1, task2)
    .ContinueWith(_ => new Result3(task1.Result, task2.Result))
    .PipeTo(Self);

...

Receive<Result3>(msg => { ... });
```